# Ember Route: Cannot read property ‘id’ of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm getting this error, where I am trying to retrieve a user that DO NOT exist on purpose ofcouse:

> Error while processing route: user Cannot read property 'id' of
>   undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Instead of this console error, can I give the user an error message saying, 'the user does not exist' or something like that through the route or a controller to the view?

Heres my route

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('user', { path: '/user/:user_id' });
});
```

And here i retrieve the user

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
    },
});
```

Hope you understand and can help me proceed. Thanks in regards!

Comment: When the user does not exist, what kind of response do you return from the server?

Comment: Perhaps cast an if statement to my view if user found render him if not say 'user does not exist'

Comment: No, I need to know what your server's response to the missing person request is. Ideally you should return a 404 status, but it seems as if you might not be.

Comment: As for now I'm not having any backend returning responses. I'm just working with Fixtures, trying to figure this Ember stuff out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure why missing fixtures data is giving you that particular error, but you can catch errors in routes using the `error` event. You can read about it [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_error). You'll have to do something like this:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
    },
    actions: {
        error: function(error, transition) {
            // Display some sort of message
            alert("Sorry, we couldn't find that user.");
            // Redirect to a different part of the application
            this.transitionTo('index');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahh this work well! Is there a way to pass a string to my user view, saying 'this user does not exist' etc?

Comment: Or should I just transition to a user 404 page?

Comment: If you're just getting started with Ember, transitioning to a 404 page might be the easiest way to do it.